# playing swf external file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to play a external SWF file (which is in server) in client side. It is working when I run through flash, but when double click on .swf it shows a dialog box:

> Adobe Flash Player Security To let this application communicate with the internet click Settings.

So what settings do we need to change to play the swf file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your Flash Player that the file is trusted to load content remotely.  Go to the Flash settings panel here: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

With this panel you can add trusted locations in your local file system.  If you add a folder to this, all subfolders will also become trusted.